# Velodyne 32E GPS driver

Tags: gps, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, All,

I remember there was a discussion on GPS driver of Velodyne 32E sometimes ago. I am just wandering what the status of that driver is. Is there anyone developing this driver? If it is already in progress, how can I contribute?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/82236/velodyne-32e-gps-driver/) by [BenMa](https://answers.ros.org/users/2964/benma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2013-09-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There has been no concrete work done that I know about.

There has been [some discussion](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/15) of adding support for the 64E S2 model's IMU and GPS data. While the 32E could be handled in a separate driver (I believe), that is not the case for 64E models with GPS attached.

If we're going to support one GPS, we might as well support the other.

Help with gathering data, coding or testing would be welcome.

**EDIT**: there is now an experimental `gps_imu` [branch in the source repository](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/tree/gps_imu). It's not yet ready to release, but user testing would be helpful. If you do try it, please post your results (both positive and negative) to [issue #24](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/issues/24).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2